# Connect two devices on a same wireless network

Tags: android, networking

Is it possible to connect two Android devices into a same wireless network (Access Point) and communicate (e.g. send/receive messages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to run a server app on one device, and a client app on the other.

## Server

You will need to create a `Service` running in the background and listening for connections on a port. This service should implement a [ServerSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) which can listen for incoming requests and send replies.

## Client

You can create a client that will connect to the server using [Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html). This can probably be an `Activity` with an interface, but be sure to do all of your network connections on a background thread, using eg. `AsyncTask`, or else your main UI thread will block and the app may crash.

Comment: the devices will use the nearby AP as medium to communicate?by using server-client socket, the device itself is no need to create a hotspot, right?

Comment: @Carson That's right -- you will need to make sure that the two devices are connected to the same AP via wifi, no need for a hotspot. You'll need to figure out the IP address of the server to connect the client to it.

Comment: But what if you don't know device IP addresses up front, how would one device make connection to the other?